# SQL query with custom column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to write a query in SQL Server that will give me some information about some tables I have. I have 2 tables w/ sample data:

**person**

```
pid     surname gender
196     Kelly   F
248     Hoskin  M
375     Walker  M
```

**degree**

```
pid     title                   is_doctoral
196     Master of Science       1
248     Doctor of Philosophy    0
```

The result I want is some analysis on male and female information:

**result**

```
Gender      # Students  Doctorate Degrees Held      Master Degrees Held         Graduation Rate
Males       2           1                           0                           50%
Females     1           0                           1                           100%
```

I cannot figure out how to create the custom first column in the result table (male, female), and I am not sure how to do the conditional sums. I am a beginner at SQL and would appreciate any help. Could someone create a query to gain that result? If I see the query I will be able to understand it from there.

Comment: Where is the information for graduation rate captured? I can't see it in your data. Is it implied that if the pid for a student isn't in the degree table then they should be counted as "not graduated"?

Comment: Yes it is implied that the two "persons" with a degree record are graduates, and the third person is not a graduate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table person(
    pid int,
    surname varchar(50),
    gender char(1)
)
create table degree(
    pid int,
    title varchar(50),
    is_doctoral varchar(5)
)
insert into person values
(196, 'Kelly', 'F'),
(248, 'Hoskin', 'M'),
(375, 'Walker', 'M')
insert into degree values
(196, 'Master of Science', 'TRUE'),
(248, 'Doctor of Philosophy', 'FALSE');
```

**SOLUTION**

```
select
    case when p.gender = 'F' then 'Female' else 'Male'end as Gender,
    count(*) as [# of Students],
    sum(case when d.is_doctoral = 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 end) as [Doctorate Degrees Held],
    sum(case when d.is_doctoral = 'FALSE' then 1 else 0 end) as [Masters Degrees Held],
    convert(varchar(10), (cast((count(d.pid) * 1.0)/count(*) * 100 as decimal))) + '%' as [Graduation Rate]
from person p
left join degree d
    on d.pid = p.pid
group by p.gender
order by p.gender desc
```

Comment: Slightly different variation, but you were quicker than I: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a5a5/4

Comment: Nice! Either way is correct. Updated my answer for the is_doctoral column.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is perfect. I understand now how cases and function calls work within SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for the [case statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php)

```
SELECT
CASE gender
  WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
  WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
END as string_gender
FROM person;
```